# Primeng dropdown display input field in it

Tags: drop-down-menu, primeng, primeng-datatable

What could I do about the non-essencial input field? The dropdown works correctly, but it is bad from visual point.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY97Y.jpg)

Code:


<p-dropdown [options]="optionsForDropdown" [(ngModel)]="rowData.linkCat" appendTo="body"
optionLabel="label" optionValue="value">


{{rowData.linkCat}}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have a style that overrides the PrimeNG style of the input container.

The container div of the input has a class to hide it.

For PrimeNG >= 10 the class is `p-hidden-accessible`
For older versions it's `ui-helper-hidden-accessible`

This div should have this css applied to it

```
border: 0;
clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
height: 1px;
margin: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
```